# Stub index points to a file without PSI: com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.UnknownFileType@23713b43

Tags: android, android-studio

Making app in Android Studio with Gradle I get this error:

> Stub index points to a file without PSI: com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.UnknownFileType@23713b43

Answer (score 38):

Same problem here.

This [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000755010-PhpStorm-keeps-indexing-over-and-over-again) is a thread on JetBrain's community forum.

The comments suggest that you do the following:

- Go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

This worked for me.